# why datetime.now() and datetime.utcnow() return different timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, utc

I'm working with datetime and find it difficult to understand how timestamp() works, I (in east coast) want to transform the datetime into timestamp, but I found following difference. Can anyone shed somelight how each of the two code works, are they suppose to act differently (roughly a difference of four hours)?

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
#1590436949.187297
datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
#1590422553.042119
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62286398/10197418

Answer (score 5):

The [`timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method returns a POSIX timestamp / seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01) which always refers to UTC.

**The Problem:** if you call the `timestamp()` method on a naïve datetime object, Python will assume that the datetime object holds ***local time***.

Although the `utcnow()` in `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` might suggest otherwise, it gives you a naïve datetime object. That is, it does not "know" it's in UTC. Therefore, if you call the `timestamp()` method, Python *assumes* that the datetime object passed to the function is local time and calculates the timestamp as such. It is then not what you would get from [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time).

On the other hand, in `datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()`, you pass a timezone-aware datetime object to `timestamp()`. That is correct in the sense that it gives you `time.time()`.

Illustration:

```
import datetime
import time
import dateutil
localtzname = time.tzname[time.daylight]

# naive:
dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
# timezone-aware:
dt_now_loc = datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.gettz(localtzname))
dt_now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
# reference:
ts = time.time()

print(dt_now.timestamp())
# 1590424623.226529

print(dt_now_loc.timestamp())
# 1590424623.226529

print(dt_now_utc.timestamp())
# 1590424623.226529

print(ts)
# 1590424623.2265291
```

As you can see, even though `dt_now` is naïve, Python returns the same timestamp as you get from the localized `dt_now_loc` or from `time.time()`.

**In summary,** `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` can be pretty misleading and I would recommend avoiding it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The things is I want to covert all the time format ( could be either naive or with tzinfo depending on the source) to a time zone free UTC time, so there will not be confusion no matter what, that's why I use utcnow() from the beginning.

Comment: @xappppp: if you ask me, use datetime objects with tzinfo set (tz aware) if you want to avoid confusion (due to the fact that Python will treat naive as local). Or stick to timestamps like POSIX which always refer to UTC.