# How do I get a naive datetime object that correctly uses UTC inputs and preserves POSIX time stamp?

Tags: python-datetime

After being bitten badly several times by this, I remain flummoxed by the `datetime` module's insistence on utilizing the local time zone when creating `datetime` objects.  What I want is a naive `datetime` object created from UTC date/time info, which the following code does not do:

```
> dt0 = dt.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1,hour=0,minute=0, tzinfo=None)
> print(dt0)
2020-01-01 00:00:00

> ts0 = dt0.timestamp()
> print(ts0)
1577858400.0

> dt1 = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts0)
> print(dt1)
2020-01-01 06:00:00
```

As we can see, the timestamp associated with `dt0` assumed that the time data provided needed to be converted from my time zone (Chicago) to UTC first.

If I explicitly specify the time zone, I get a time zone-aware object (which I don't want), which I can convert to time zone-naive by getting the time stamp and then passing it through `utcfromtimestamp()`. So the following works up to a point, but see the final line:

```
> dt0 = dt.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1,hour=0,minute=0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
> print(dt0)
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00

> ts0 = dt0.timestamp()
> print(ts0)
1577836800.0

> dt1 = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts0)
> print(dt1)
2020-01-01 00:00:00

> ts1 = dt1.timestamp()
> print(ts1)
1577858400.0
```

It changed the timestamp, apparently assuming again that `dt1` is supposed to be in my local timezone!

I also thought the following might work, but it clearly doesn't, and this is where I am most baffled:  the simple act of eliminating time zone info results in an unwanted timezone conversion. To me, a long-time user of `datetime`, this feels like a bug, not a feature.

```
> dt0 = dt.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1,hour=0,minute=0, tzinfo=utc)
> print(dt0)
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00

> dt0 = dt0.replace(tzinfo=None)
> print(dt0)
2020-01-01 00:00:00

> ts0 = dt0.timestamp()
> print(ts0)
1577858400.0

> dt1 = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts0)
> print(dt1)
2020-01-01 06:00:00
```

Additional context:  I work with geophysical data sets that are *always* referenced to UTC.  Sometimes the time tags are actually stored as POSIX time stamps.  I don't want to *ever* have to mess with time zones or worry about Python comparing the wrong datetime value with the times in the data sets.  I increasingly wish there were a third datetime object that is neither "naive" nor "time zone aware" but rather is *explicitly* and *exclusively* UTC.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286398/python-utcfromtimestamp-vs-fromtimestamp-when-the-timestamp-is-based-on-utcnow

Answer (score 3):

As asked, the answer to this is "you don't", because in Python naïve datetimes represent local time and not UTC; this is one of the reasons that [you should not use `utcnow` or `utcfromtimestamp`](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) — and there is an [explicit warning about this in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp). If you want to tell Python that your `datetime` represents UTC, you attach a UTC time zone to it. You do not make it clear in your question at all what is unsatisfactory about making a datetime *explicitly UTC* by attaching a UTC `tzinfo` to it.

If you have a naïve datetime that you know represents UTC, you should simply attach `datetime.timezone.utc` to it, like so:

```
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

If you don't want to do this for some reason, you can also get a POSIX timestamp from a naïve datetime representing UTC (but not one representing any other offset) with simple calendar arithmetic:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(12345)
>>> ts = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)
>>> ts
12345.0
```

This works because POSIX timestamps do not include leap seconds, so a simple calendar delta will work.

Comment: I appreciate the blog post giving context for why things are the way they are, and why they can't be fixed, but I do detect a bit of "blame the user", when I don't think that's entirely fair.  I've been using datetime since long before Python 3 came along, and your blog post makes clear that some things changed significantly in Python 3 that no user could anticipate.  For any programming involving non-local data, I believe that local time should not be the default assumption, and operations on naive objects should not quietly introduce time zone assumptions without the programmer's knowledge.

Comment: @GrantPetty Is the question "How do I do this?" or "Why can't I do this?" I answered the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you could use:

```
dt.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1,hour=0,minute=0, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

That returns:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: I might have edited both the title and and the content after you answered.  Please take another look, because there's also an issue with the timestamp.

Comment: Right I see, replacing the tzinfo changes the timestamp back to... local.. I guess. New title points that out better. I'll have another look