# python datetime .timestamp() doesnt give accurate timestamp. It gets behind by 7 minutes when I convert it back

Tags: python, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

I am using python 3.6

I converted midnight of "US/Pacific" timezone to unix timestamp.

When I convert the timestamp back to "US/Pacific" local time, I see its 7 minutes before the midnight.

Can anyone shade light on what is happening?

```
>>> (
    datetime(2021, 5, 5, 0, 0)
    .replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Pacific"))
    .timestamp()
)

>>> 1620201180.0

>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1620201180.0)
>>> datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 5, 7, 53)

>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1620201180.0, tz=pytz.timezone("US/Pacific"))
>>> datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 5, 0, 53, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

FYI I am located at "Asia/Kathmandu" timezone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473721/weird-timezone-issue-with-pytz)

Comment: Also related: [python: utcfromtimestamp vs fromtimestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62286398/10197418)

Comment: Basically: with pytz, **use localize**, not replace. And [Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html), it's pretty confusing ;-)