# Python astimezone 1 hour behind expected result compared to adding timedelta to UTC date

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to do some testing with time offsets from UTC. I have tried two methods as shown in the code listing below:

1. Adding `timedelta` to UTC `datetime`
2. Using `astimezone` method on UTC `datetime`

In the short test program below the resultant date from `astimezone` method is 1 hour behind. I do not understand why??

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

if __name__ == "__main__":
    utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
    target_time = int((utc_now + timedelta(hours=10)).timestamp())
    timestamp = utc_now.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=10)))

    print(f"datetime.utcnow() = {utc_now.isoformat()}")
    print(
        f"datetime.utcnow() + 10 hours using timedelta = {datetime.fromtimestamp(target_time).isoformat()}"
    )
    print(f"datetime.utcnow() + 10 hours using astimezone = {timestamp.isoformat()}")
```

```sh
datetime.utcnow() = 2021-09-04T16:12:53.753059
datetime.utcnow() + 10 hours using timedelta = 2021-09-05T02:12:53
datetime.utcnow() + 10 hours using astimezone = 2021-09-05T01:12:53.753059+10:00
```

**Edit - Update - datetime.now (timezone.utc )**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

if __name__ == "__main__":
    utc_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

    target_time = int((utc_now + timedelta(hours=10)).timestamp())
    timestamp = utc_now.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=10)))

    print(f"datetime.utcnow() = {utc_now.isoformat()}")
    print(
        "datetime.utcnow() + 10 hours using timedelta ="
        f" {datetime.fromtimestamp(target_time).isoformat()}"
    )
    print(f"datetime.utcnow() + 10 hours using astimezone = {timestamp.isoformat()}")
```

Tried to make timezone aware UTC datetime now with the same result.

How do I use `astimezone` to get an equivalent result?

Comment: Regarding  your  edit, `datetime.fromtimestamp` offers the same trap (naive datetime) if you don't set `tz`...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62006348/10197418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the assumption that `datetime.utcnow()` gives you UTC. It does not. It gives you a [naive datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) that Python still treats as ***local time*** although hours, minutes etc. *resemble* UTC.

Set `tzinfo` adequately to get consistent results (don't use utcnow at all if possible! - unless you know what you're doing):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

utc_now = datetime(2021, 9, 4, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
target_time = int((utc_now + timedelta(hours=10)).timestamp())
timestamp = utc_now.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=10)))

print(f"utc_now = {utc_now.isoformat()}")
print(f"utc_now + 10 hours using timedelta = {datetime.fromtimestamp(target_time, tz=timezone.utc).isoformat()}")
print(f"utc_now + 10 hours using astimezone = {timestamp.isoformat()}")

# utc_now = 2021-09-04T00:00:00+00:00
# utc_now + 10 hours using timedelta = 2021-09-04T10:00:00+00:00
# utc_now + 10 hours using astimezone = 2021-09-04T10:00:00+10:00
```

The key here is understanding the difference between naive datetime (=local time by default) and aware datetime (the time zone you set...). For more time zone handling, see also the [zoneinfo lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html).

Answer (score 1):

an aspect that is also relevant here in the context of working with time zones in Python: `timedelta` arithmetic is wall time arithmetic - i.e. what you would observe on a wall clock that gets adjusted to DST active/inactive. In the following example, I add 24 hours:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

t0 = datetime(2021, 10, 30, 20, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin")) # DST active
t1 = t0 + timedelta(hours=24) # add 24 hours -> DST is inactive
print(t0, t1)
# 2021-10-30 20:00:00+02:00 2021-10-31 20:00:00+01:00
print((t1-t0).total_seconds()/3600)
# 24.0
```

Now watch how they become 25 hours - not because of magic but because of the wall clock would show local time, not UTC...

```
t0_utc, t1_utc = t0.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC")), t1.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC"))
print(t0_utc, t1_utc)
# 2021-10-30 18:00:00+00:00 2021-10-31 19:00:00+00:00
print((t1_utc-t0_utc).total_seconds()/3600)
# 25.0
```

Note: since Europe/Berlin is the time zone my OS is configured to use, this would also work with `t0` and `t1` being naive datetime objects!

Comment: Quote: _timedelta arithmetic is wall time arithmetic_: Not if the two tzinfo objects are different, then it is real time.

Comment: The specs state: _If both are aware and have different tzinfo attributes, a-b acts as if a and b were first converted to naive UTC datetimes first._ So the difference is the same as (a.timestamp() -b.timestamp()), the "real time" being timestamp(). This is very different from "wallclock", which is timetuple().