# Why the difference between datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) and datetime.datetime.utcnow()

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

If you call `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)` you get something like `datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 1, 33, 19, 684253, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`.

If you call `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, you get something like `datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 1, 33, 20, 283212)`.

The results seem the equivalent, but they aren't, because the **timestamps** will differ. Eg. calling `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp() - datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` returns (for me): `-18000.000012159348`.

Why is that?

```
import datetime

print()
print(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())

print()
print(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp())
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
print(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp() - datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69057022/10197418 - to illustrate how confusing this can become

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is documented. It happens because `utcnow()` returns a naive datetime.

> `datetime.utcnow()`
>
> Return the current UTC date and time, with `tzinfo` `None`.
>
> This is like `now()`, but returns the current UTC date and time, as a
> naive datetime object. An aware current UTC datetime can be obtained
> by calling `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

That is why the documentation also says of `datetime.now()`

> This function is preferred over `today()` and `utcnow()`.

Comment: A **naive timestamp** is a timestamp without a timezone?

Comment: @étale-cohomology The timestamp isn't naive, the `datetime` is. Docs: "Whether a naive object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it is up to the program whether a particular number represents metres, miles, or mass. Naive objects are easy to understand and to work with, at the cost of ignoring some aspects of reality." Some consider naive datetimes to have been a fundamental design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

`utcnow` creates a naive `datetime` instance, because there was no UTC timezone object when it was introduced in Python.  From the documentation for [`timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> Naive datetime instances are assumed to represent local time and this method relies on the platform C mktime() function to perform the conversion.