# datetime with fixedoffset to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two datetime objects which I want to subtract - however they both need to be in same format

I tried to convert datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-240)] (eastern time zone) however I run into errors. Other datetime object is datetime64[ns] which is already in est timezone

```
1) df['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
   error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

2) df['date'].replace(tzinfo=None)
   error: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'

3) df['date'].dt_tz.replace(tzinfo=None)
   error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt_tz'
```

Comment: Try `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and then try to subtract objects. (`import pandas as pd` should come first.)

Comment: datetime as a datatype has no format, you mean both need to be aware datetime (tzinfo set) or naive datetime (tzinfo None)? Also, what are you actually trying to achieve, can you create a [mre]?

Comment: `df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` and `df['date'].dt.tz_localize(None)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, if you have mixed time zones or UTC offsets, you will get

> TypeError: DatetimeArray subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones

when trying to calculate a timedelta. The error basically tells you how to avoid it: convert everything to the same tz, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'date0': pd.to_datetime(["2021-08-01 00:00 -04:00"]), # should be US/Eastern
                   'date1': pd.to_datetime(["2021-08-01 01:00"]) # should be US/Eastern as well
                   })

#                       date0               date1
# 0 2021-08-01 00:00:00-04:00 2021-08-01 01:00:00

# date0 already has a UTC offset but we can set a proper time zone:
df['date0'] = df['date0'].dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')

# date1 is naive, i.e. does not have a time zone, so we need to localize:
df['date1'] = df['date1'].dt.tz_localize('America/New_York')

# since both datetime columns now have the same time zone, we can calculate:
print(df['date1'] - df['date0'])

# 0   0 days 01:00:00
# dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

Python's datetime isn't that picky, you can easily calculate timedelta from datetime objects with different time zones:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9

d0 = datetime(2021, 1, 1, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("UTC"))
d1 = datetime(2020, 12, 31, 20, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))

print(d1-d0)
# 1:00:00
```

Keep in mind that Python's timedelta arithmetic is wall-time arithmetic; you can do weird stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065734/10197418). So it's sometimes less obvious what's going on I'd say.

Comment: Thanks for the response - somehow for first datetime parameter even though it is in EST timezone I had to convert it pd.to_datetime((df['date']).dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')) and since 2nd one to match same format I had to localize it pd.to_datetime((df['date1']).dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern')) to get both dates in same format for performing substraction

Comment: since 2nd time didn't have tz I had to localize it first. Since both are EST only I skipped the step of converting them to UTC and doing subtraction.

Comment: @oneday ok so my comment on your question actually was the point? Anyways, glad that your problem is solved. Regarding UTC or Eastern time, it doesn't matter which, just have to be the same.

Comment: yes that is correct - ur point is accurate

Comment: @oneday I've adjusted the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

While @MrFuppes answer is detailed for generic case since one of my dataframe was already in tz format I had to take below steps which worked

```
Initial format
  datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-240)] (eastern time zone)

1) Step taken
 pd.to_datetime((df['date']).dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern'))

Initial Format
  datetime64[ns]

2) Step taken
 pd.to_datetime((df['date1']).dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern'))
```

This two steps brought datetime in same format for me to perform arithmetic operations